# Change record owner in Dynamics CRM plugin

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am writing a Post PLugin changing the owner. When the owner has a substitution manager, the owner is changed to the substitution manager. I tried a service.Update and an AssignRequest, but these throw an exception.

When I post the request my entity cannot update (and then throws "The request channel time out while waiting for reply after 10:00:00"). But like I see there is no recursion, because when I logged it I have only one repetition of log and it has stopped before or on line with update.

```
var assignedIncident = new AssignRequest
{
  Assignee = substManagerRef, //get it throw another method, alreay checked in test it`s correct
  Target = new EntityReference ("incident", incedentId)
};
service.Execute(assignedIncident);
```

I tried to write target in another way

```
Target = postEntityImage.ToEntityReference()
```

I tried to write simple update but the problem is the same.

```
Entity incident = new Entity("incident" , incidentId);
incident["ownerid"] = substManagerRef:
service.Update(incident);
```

Can somebody help me with that? Or maybe show the way to solve it)

Comment: Did you make sure you don’t have ownerid in filtering attribute of your post update plugin step?

Comment: I checked postentityImage.contains.Attribute("ownerid") equals true.

Comment: Image is snapshot of pre/post values. Filtering attribute and Target stores the current transaction values. If you have ownerid in filtering attribute and when you keep on updating the ownerid field - the plugin trigger in loops. Check the plugin execution depth for safe.

Comment: I already did it, log in it is by the lines like that 1-2-3-4-5-6, but 7 is after update and it stops.

Comment: do you have the same error when you change this plugin to asynchronous?

Answer (score 1):

The plugin is triggering itself and gets in a loop. The system only allows a maximum of 8 calls deep within plugins and that is the reason it throws an error and rolls back the transaction.

To solve this issue redesign your plugin in the following way:

- Register your plugin on the Update message of your entity in the PreValidation stage.
- In the plugin pick up the `Target` property from the InputParameters collection.
- This is an `Entity` type. Modify or set the `ownerid` attribute on this `Entity` object.

That is all. You do not need to do an update, your modification is now passed into the plugin pipeline.

> Note: for `EntityReference` attributes this technique only works when your plugin is registered in the PreValidation stage. For other regular attributes it also works in the PreOperation stage.